# In vscode DevContainer docker file failed to open as 'failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0'

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

When I am building the dockerfile using cli (docker build command) ,it builds the image and I am able to run the container using docker run command also.
But when I do 'reopen folder in container' via vscode Devcontainer plugin ,it fails with below error.

```
=> ERROR resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4


ERROR: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp 16.214.118.28:443: i/o timeout
```

Some forums suggested to docker logout and login again. It did not help.

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ENV http_proxy "http://web-proxy.myorg.net:8080"
ENV https_proxy "http://web-proxy.myorg.net:8080"
ENV no_proxy "127.0.0.1,localhost"
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/workspaces/automation/test/"


COPY test/poetry.lock test/pyproject.toml test/requirements.txt /tmp/

RUN python -m pip install poetry \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && cd /tmp \
    && poetry install \
    && rm -f /tmp/poetry.lock /tmp/pyproject.toml \
    && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN apt update \
    && apt install iputils-ping -y \
    && apt install git -y \
    && apt install curl -y

WORKDIR /automation/
```

Comment: I think what you need is [attach a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container)